# How to receive mobile data disabled event while wifi is connected

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi

`ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` can't receive broadcast when current network type is wifi,how can I receive related events when user click disable or enable mobile data.
my code like :

> ```
> context.register(MyBroadCast,newIntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
> ```

can't receive BroadCast while I use wifi connect to net

but I found I can get status like this

> ```
>  Settings.Secure.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(), "mobile_data", -1)
> ```

it looks like `contentprovider(URI,...)`,I want to `registerObserver` for this but I can't find related Uri,anyone can help me ?

Comment: please consider marking correct if my answer helped

Comment: You are not getting mobile data on/off signal when wifi is on.  Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize APIs of ConnectivityManager: particularly in your use case you are interested in registerDefaultNetworkCallback():

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConnectivityManager manager;
    private final ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            super.onAvailable(network);
            // this ternary operation is not quite true, because non-metered doesn't yet mean, that it's wifi
            // nevertheless, for simplicity let's assume that's true
            Log.i("vvv", "connected to " + (manager.isActiveNetworkMetered() ? "LTE" : "WIFI"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Network network) {
            super.onLost(network);
            Log.i("vvv", "losing active connection");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        manager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        manager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
    }
}
```

you cannot know beforehand, whether device will eventually connect to LTE or no at the time, when WIFI gets disconnected. Thus, you can adopt following approach: post an action on a handler to happen in a second and within this action cancel the call. If connection appears anytime soon - unschedule previously posted action. If you end up being in Runnable code, than connection wasn't established quickly, which means, that you should end the call.

```
 public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ConnectivityManager manager;

        private final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private final ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                Log.i("vvv", "connected to " + (manager.isActiveNetworkMetered() ? "LTE" : "WIFI"));

                // we've got a connection, remove callbacks (if we have posted any)
                handler.removeCallbacks(endCall);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLost(Network network) {
                super.onLost(network);
                Log.i("vvv", "losing active connection");

                // Schedule an event to take place in a second
                handler.postDelayed(endCall, 1000);
            }
        };

        private final Runnable endCall = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // if execution has reached here - feel free to cancel the call
                // because no connection was established in a second
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            manager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            manager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
            handler.removeCallbacks(endCall);
        }
    }
```

Comment: only get,I want callback event